# select neighbour polygons in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a database of few milion records (all houses in my country). Now I want to select all records who have a neighbouring record (a house attached to it) and give this a status 'T'. Each record has a geometry column, looking like this:

```
POLYGON(( 254059.737 593504.637 0.0, 254059.227 593500.0 0.0, 254059.216 593499.899 0.0, 254058.242 593500.0 0.0, 254057.914 593500.034 0.0, 254057.893 593500.0 0.0, 254057.807 593499.863 0.0, 254052.074 593490.692 0.0, 254052.182 593490.639 0.0, 254058.138 593490.002 0.0, 254057.932 593488.165 0.0, 254074.487 593486.413 0.0, 254075.981 593500.0 0.0, 254076.265 593502.583 0.0, 254076.561 593502.55 0.0, 254076.594 593502.847 0.0, 254059.737 593504.637 0.0))
```

Is there a possibility to do this with an sql statement? I have never used SQL so I am a complete rookie. A detailled explanation is preferred.

I started with:

```
SELECT id, geometry, 'T'::text as type 
FROM houses 
WHERE
```

I think I have to add some intersect function at the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/194023/1872)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) or [ST_Crosses](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Crosses.html).

So, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    h1.id,
    'T'::text as type
FROM
    houses h1,
    houses h2
WHERE
    h1.id <> h2.id and
    ST_Intersects(h1.geometry, h2.geometry)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have 8 million records. I cannot write 'h1.id' till 'h8000000'. Is there no automatic way where for each house, he checks whether or not it has a house with the same line segment or something?

Comment: You don't need to do that, this select will collect every house geometry that has an intersection, and it will tell you, which id-s intersects with them. So if id1 has intersection with id2 and id3, it will show something like this: row1: id1 | id2 | T; row2: id1 | id3 | T;
Just try the select with limit 100 and you will see.

Comment: I see what you mean. Try the new select, I edited the question. This will select every id, that has at least one intersected "neighbour".

Comment: Thanks. I did try it, but even with the limit on 10, the query is still running even after 10 minutes. Not sure if it is because of my dataset or if something else is wrong

Comment: This answer is essentially correct the slowness is a different matter which needs to be addressed with indexes (but for an 8 million row table used on a self join it might not be easy)

Comment: maybe you can speed it up using some other restraints. maybe there is the city in another column, so you can add 'h1.city=h2.city' to your where clause. i'm not sure about this but some distance restraint could help as well: 'st_dwithin(h1.geometry, h2.geometry, 100)'